# Stick the last image of the carousel to the first

Tags: html

I have created a HTML-CSS carousel and it works (see: https://jsfiddle.net/PPSkola/s5v4ptxf/8/ ) but if someone could help me to connect the last icon with the first one without gap, so that the circle would be complete, please...
Here is the CSS:

```
<style>
    .slider {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0px;
            background-color: #e2e9f0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .slide-track {
            display: flex;
            padding-left: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            animation: 25s scroll infinite linear;
        }
        @keyframes scroll {
            from {transform: translateX(0px);}
            to   {transform: translateX(-90%);}
        }
        .slide-track:hover {
            animation-play-state: paused;
        }
        .slide {
            width: 150px !important;
        }
        .slide img {
            width: 100px !important;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: which icon? I can't see images and icon. please send codepen link so i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're having a gap, you need something to fill it up, the best way is to use the same track so that people would see it as a seamless transition.

1. You just have to duplicate the HTML code of the `slider-track`.

```
<!-- something like this -->
<div class="slide-track">...</div>
<div class="slide-track clone">...</div>
```

2. Then you need to make 2 tracks display on the same row, there are many ways in CSS to achieve this, here's one:

```
.slider { overflow: hidden; }
.slider-inner { white-space: nowrap; }
.slide-track { display: inline-flex; }
```

- `.slider`: this is the container to prevent things inside not overflowing.
- `.slider-inner`: this is the wrapper to keep the tracks in one line.
- `.slide-track`: once the parent has `white-space: nowrap;` and the child is `inline`, all children will always stay on the same line.

3. Now comes the animation. With the HTML and CSS setup, you will have something like this.

[image: demo-sketch]

Apply your CSS animation for the 2 tracks and you will have the slider run seamlessly.

```
.slide-track {
    animation: 5s scroll infinite linear;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    from {transform: translateX(0px);}
    to   {transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phucbm/fmz3j5a2).

Comment: Great idea! I used your idea to double the "slide-track clone" container. But I made it more simple:
.slider {display: flex; width: 200%;}
and both: "slide-track" and "clone" do exactly the same things.

Thanks a LOT!

Comment: That's a way. I'm glad it helped.